# systemctl isolate - what's the reasoning behind the word "isolate"?

Tags: centos, redhat-enterprise-linux

I don't find `systemctl isolate` a very easy set of commands to remember.

What's the reasoning behind the use of the word `isolate` for switching between the older, but what I found a lot more user-friendly, `run levels`?

Answer (score 17):

I was wondering the same thing. From the [systemctl man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html):

> isolate UNIT
>
> Start the unit specified on the command line and its dependencies and
>   stop all others, unless they have IgnoreOnIsolate=yes (see
>   systemd.unit(5)). If a unit name with no extension is given, an
>   extension of ".target" will be assumed.
>
> This is similar to changing the runlevel in a traditional init system.
>   The isolate command will immediately stop processes that are not
>   enabled in the new unit, possibly including the graphical environment
>   or terminal you are currently using.
>
> Note that this is allowed only on units where AllowIsolate= is
>   enabled. See systemd.unit(5) for details.

So the word "isolate" means run the requested unit, and make sure nothing else is running (with a few exceptions mentioned above).

Since runlevels have been replaced by targets (which are more or less just a set of services that you want to be running in a certain situation, like for `multi-user` or `graphical` usage), you can switch to a "runlevel" by starting the equivalent target and stopping anything that is not part of the new target - using `isolate`.